# fr<TAB> is not inserting \frac{}{} in CDLaTeX

Tags: latex, auctex, tex

I typed `fr<TAB>` as is written in the manual but got only a fr and a tab. The `\frac{}{}` is not correctly inserted and so does `sq`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a more complete, step-by-step recipe, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Answer (score 1):

By typing `C-c ?` you can activate the *CDLaTeX Help*, in which you will see `TEXT/MATH`, `TEXT/`, or `MATH`. This means that the function or abbreviation can only activated in the `text mode`, `math mode` or both of them of latex. 
Insert the desired command between $$ to activate it.
This is pretty much a LaTeX problem than an Emacs problem.